# Making servlets with Wamp Apache

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee

My question is in the title, can I use WampApache instead of Tomcat to code servlets? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) generally stands for Windows, Apache, MySql, PHP/Python, so usually there's no Java in such a stack, so the answer would be you can't do this...